# Getting coordinates of Line or MultiLine using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, line, coordinates, multiline

We can get point layer coordinates through the following code, but I want to know the coordinates of Line or MultiLine. How to get these coordinates?

```py
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("layerName")[0]

features = layer.getFeatures()

for feature in features:
  geom = feature.geometry()
  print(geom.asPoint().x(), geom.asPoint().y())
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by *"coordinates of the line/multiline"*, all vertex coordinates or just coordinates of end and start points or coordinates of line centroid/midpoin/center? Check these https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/304755/first-and-last-point-of-multilinestring-objects-in-qgis-3 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116211/how-to-get-coordinates-of-line. What do you want as an output, e.g. a list, or dict as well  as when it is a multiline would like to have a list with lists or just a flat list or just a normal `print()`?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6):

### For single part LineString:

```py
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Single parts")[0]

for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    for pnt in feature.geometry().asPolyline():
        print(pnt.x(), pnt.y())
```

### For multipart LineString:

```py
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("folyo")[0]

for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    for part in feature.geometry().asMultiPolyline():
        print("part")
        for pnt in part:
            print(pnt.x(), pnt.y())
```

Tested in QGIS 3.16.1

[`asMultiPolyline()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.14/core/QgsGeometry.html#qgis.core.QgsGeometry.asMultiPolyline) and [`asPolyline()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.14/core/QgsGeometry.html#qgis.core.QgsGeometry.asPolyline) return a list of points, so you can use indexes.

To check the layer geometry type use the [`geometryType()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.14/core/QgsVectorLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.geometryType) method of a layer.

To separate single and multi types use the [`isSingleType()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.14/core/QgsWkbTypes.html#qgis.core.QgsWkbTypes.isSingleType) method.

Here is the code for it:

```py
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("your_layer")[0]

if layer.geometryType() ==  QgsWkbTypes.LineGeometry:

    for feature in layer.getFeatures():
        geom = feature.geometry()

        if QgsWkbTypes.isSingleType(geom.wkbType()):
            # single
            for pnt in geom.asPolyline():
                print(pnt.x(), pnt.y())
        else:
            # multipart
            for part in geom.asMultiPolyline():
                print("part")
                for pnt in part:
                    print(pnt.x(), pnt.y())
```

Comment: yeah it's correct, but if i don't know the layer type then how can I mention ```geom.asMultiPolyline(), it can be geom.asPolyline() or geom.asPoint(). "verts = geom.asMultiPolyline() # use geom.asPolyline() for line geometry" 
instead of hard coding to geom.asMultiPolyline(), can I use some run time API(). which will decide whether to use geom.asMultiPolyline()/ geom.asPolyline() or geom.asPoint()```

Comment: See my updates in the answer

Answer (score 3):

If you want to extract the xy of vertices of a MultiPolyline geometry you can use the following code:

```py
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("layerName")[0]

features = layer.getFeatures()
for feature in features:
    geom = feature.geometry()
    verts = geom.asMultiPolyline() # use geom.asPolyline() for line geometry
    for vert in verts:
        for i in range(len(vert)):
            print(vert[i].x(), vert[i].y())
```

The output will be like this:

```
-3487202.783144876 10010395.30478035
-3428476.505393841 10049595.900699263
-3428476.505393841 10049595.900699263
-3374593.995628879 9923727.261801671
-3428476.505393841 10049595.900699263
-3359626.0983730364 10059037.052994486
```

[image]

Comment: yeah it's correct, but if i don't know the layer type then how can I mention ```geom.asMultiPolyline(), it can be geom.asPolyline() or geom.asPoint().```
"verts = geom.asMultiPolyline() # use geom.asPolyline() for line geometry"

Comment: Add `print(geom)` to your code right after the `geom` variable, it will print the type of the geometry plus the coordinate of the vertices.

Comment: But I want the coordinates separately.